# Корректность формирования post/put/delete запроса ASP NET Core

Tags: http, asp.net-core

Доброго времени суток!

В общем и целом, хотелось бы узнать практики по формированию запросов

Допустим, есть метод изменения состояния того или иного свойства объекта. В asp есть атрибуты FromQuery и FromHeader (пока что они меня интересуют) для формирования метода в контроллере. Что из этого предпочтительнее использовать (с точки зрения безопасности тоже)? Разницу я понимаю, но не нашел на просторах что же все таки грамотнее использовать.
И вообще, можно ли хранить идентификатор объекта в заголовке, допустим, когда удалением или создаём элемент в какой-нибудь коллекции?